# Address of a PCI device obtained from lspci -vvv is invalid?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, dd, pci

I try to read a PCI device memory area (I know at what offset from that device is stuff I look for) so first I try to obtain the system memory address where that PCI device memory has been mapped. In order to do so I do **lspci -vvv** and I get:

```
00:1a.8 Memory controller
Subsystem: Dell Device
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 139
Memory at 601d198000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Memory at 601d000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: nvm-mem-drv
```

So far so good, now I make an attempt to look whats in that memory with the help of dd

```
dd if=/dev/mem iflag=skip_bytes skip=‭412803399680 bs=512 count=1 | hexdump -C
```

Surprisingly all I get is:

> dd: error reading '/dev/mem': **Bad address** 0+0 records in 0+0 records
> out 0 bytes copied, 9,3556e-05 s, 0,0 kB/s

I set "surprisingly" since such a method worked for me on other platforms.

Now the question is why **dd** says bad addrees? The very first thing I have noticed is that the address on that platform is longer than on others (by exactly two digits). So I though maybe what I pass to **skip** got overflow - I tried to fix it by specifying "skip" in units of 512 block but that method as well returned **Bad address**.
So I am a bit lost here, is lspci laying to me or what is going on? :|

PS: I have also verifed that kernel CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM is not set. I can read other addresses just fine.